# IndexController newly added method give 404 error

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am new to the zf so I guess this is a basic level problem for you guys.I have a zf1 
project and I am studying the code.In my IndexController all the old methods are working except my new method,It gives me a 404 error.Do i need to specify the method names anywhere? or what can I do for this error ?

my controller path - application/modules/default/controllers/IndexController.php

my newly added method that is not work in IndexController.php

```
    public function mytestAction() {  }
```

Old method that is work in IndexController.php

```
    public function termsconditionsAction() { }
```

views path -  application/modules/default/views/scripts/index/mytest.phtml

Comment: What url do you use to access it?

Comment: that cannot happen you it should work

Comment: @fauad this is working url 
http://local.myebook.com/default/index/termsconditions/
this is not working one 
http://local.myebook.com/default/index/mytest/

Comment: FYI Im in windows 7 OS

Comment: Weird! it should work. may be you added it in the wrong place. check the braces.

Comment: @Fouad yeah it should work.braces are fine.Are there any place to register these method names in zf1(config file or something). ?

Comment: No, just add the method and the corresponding view file.

Comment: Make sure you're in development mode, ie `resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions=1`

Comment: @phil no it's not working.

Comment: Not working means what ? , which exception does it throw ??

Comment: no exceptions shows just give 404 error.It's not executing my function.

Comment: Layer between `default/index/mytest` and `mytestAction` of your controller is router. Update your post with routes listing please.